# How to detect if machine is joined to domain?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I detect whether the machine is joined to an Active Directory domain (versus in Workgroup mode)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can PInvoke to Win32 API's such as [NetGetDcName](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.NetGetDCName) which will return a null/empty string for a non domain-joined machine.

Even better is [NetGetJoinInformation](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.NetGetJoinInformation) which will tell you explicitly if a machine is unjoined, in a workgroup or in a domain.

Using `NetGetJoinInformation` I put together this, which worked for me:

```
public class Test
{
    public static bool IsInDomain()
    {
        Win32.NetJoinStatus status = Win32.NetJoinStatus.NetSetupUnknownStatus;
        IntPtr pDomain = IntPtr.Zero;
        int result = Win32.NetGetJoinInformation(null, out pDomain, out status);
        if (pDomain != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Win32.NetApiBufferFree(pDomain);
        }
        if (result == Win32.ErrorSuccess)
        {
            return status == Win32.NetJoinStatus.NetSetupDomainName;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Domain Info Get Failed", new Win32Exception());
        }
    }
}

internal class Win32
{
    public const int ErrorSuccess = 0;

    [DllImport("Netapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern int NetGetJoinInformation(string server, out IntPtr domain, out NetJoinStatus status);

    [DllImport("Netapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr Buffer);

    public enum NetJoinStatus
    {
        NetSetupUnknownStatus = 0,
        NetSetupUnjoined,
        NetSetupWorkgroupName,
        NetSetupDomainName
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool.  But isn't there a memory leak in your function, the pDomain data returned by NetGetJoinInformation?

Comment: (not that a leak matters too much... as I'll be calling this once and caching it)

Comment: Ahh - the code sample I hacked this up from in the PInvoke site was calling NetApiBufferFree - I've added that to the sample =)

Comment: It's important to note that `NetGetJoinInformation` returns the legacy NetBIOS domain name, rather than the domain name (hence the ***Net*** in NetGetJoinInformation)

Comment: Instead of `throw new Exception("Domain Info Get Failed");` you should do `throw new Exception("Domain Info Get Failed", new Win32Exception());` insetad. The inner `Win32Exception` will internally call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` and set the error code and error message for that code in the inner exception. That is why you do `SetLastError=true` in the p/invoke signature, so that `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` will work.

Answer (score 96):

Don't fool with pinvoke if you don't have to.

Reference System.DirectoryServices, then call:

```
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetComputerDomain()
```

Throws an `ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException` if the machine is not domain-joined.
The Domain object that's returned contains the Name property you're looking for.

Comment: I always love to find that exists a managed version of almost anything.

Comment: Note to others.. **make sure you use GetComputerDomain()** (as suggested above) and **not GetCurrentDomain()**. GetCurrentDomain() blocks for ages if you're not joined to a domain.

Comment: There is a problem with this call as it takes about 2 mins on many configurations.

Comment: It just took 30 seconds to run this on a decently large corporate AD forest. :-/  Seems a little odd...

Comment: Follow-up to my previous, I was using LINQPad and using Dump() on the Domain object, which is what was taking so much time!  Just accessing the Name property of the returned Domain instance is really fast. :-)

Comment: Has anyone tried this in a read-only domain controller environment? These nice helpful .net methods have a nasty habit of baulking when all you can see is an RODC.

Comment: NOTE: This method will return the domain even in the case where a user is logged in on a local account. As a result, code that uses this to retrieve settings for a user has a nice security hole in which a user could create a local user account to impersonate someone else.  (I believe the solution to this is Environment.UserDomainName)

Comment: This solution does not work if you need to know whether the computer is joined to a domain even when it is not currently connected to the network.  In that case it will throw an ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException.

Comment: I tried this method in my azure virtual machine and it is really slow. have to use the pinvoke method.

Comment: this method will access DC of your domain

Comment: This method can be extremely slow. In some environments it can take more than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 25):

Can also be called by using system.net

```
string domain = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName
```

If the domain string is empty the machine isn't bound.

Documentation on the property returned https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.domainname?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_NetworkInformation_IPGlobalProperties_DomainName

Tip, this will also work in Powershell

```
[System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties()
```

Comment: This the best answer as it is both a managed solution and the fastest.

Comment: This returns the primary DNS suffix for the computer which is not necessarily an indication that it's in AD. If you add a DNS suffix to a PC that's in a workgroup this returns that suffix name, not an empty string.

Comment: @MikeLowery According to the documentation "A String instance that contains the computer's domain name. If the computer does not belong to a domain, returns Empty." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.domainname?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_NetworkInformation_IPGlobalProperties_DomainName

Comment: @EricHerlitz I saw the documentation. Unfortunately there's ambiguity between DNS domains and AD domains. This code appears to be addressing the former.

Answer (score 9):

```
ManagementObject cs;
        using(cs = new ManagementObject("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" + System.Environment.MachineName + "'" ))
        {
            cs.Get();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}",cs["domain"].ToString());
        }
```

That should allow you to get the domain.  I believe it will be null or empty if you are part of a workgroup and not a domain.

Make sure to reference System.Management

Comment: It returns "WORKGROUP" if not in domain.  This will work (unless you're in a domain named "WORKGROUP"!), but I'll wait for a bit to see if there is a non-WMI based approach before choosing it as the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I only have my work machine to test on and I can't exactly remove it from the domain to test.

Comment: On second thought I don't think this will work.  It turns out that the name of the workgroup for my test box is actually WORKGROUP.  I think its returning the workgroup name, not a fixed value, which from an API perspective makes more sense, but it means you can't use this to determine whether its domain joined.

Comment: +1 for method is fast, not require user to be logged in, or even require access to DC to get name

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to drop Rob's Code in VB:

```
 Public Class Test
    Public Function IsInDomain() As Boolean
        Try
            Dim status As Win32.NetJoinStatus = Win32.NetJoinStatus.NetSetupUnknownStatus
            Dim pDomain As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
            Dim result As Integer = Win32.NetGetJoinInformation(Nothing, pDomain, status)

            If (pDomain <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
                Win32.NetApiBufferFree(pDomain)
            End If

            If (result = Win32.ErrorSuccess) Then
                If (status = Win32.NetJoinStatus.NetSetupDomainName) Then
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            Else
                Throw New Exception("Domain Info Get Failed")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
Public Class Win32
    Public Const ErrorSuccess As Integer = 0
    Declare Auto Function NetGetJoinInformation Lib "Netapi32.dll" (ByVal server As String, ByRef IntPtr As IntPtr, ByRef status As NetJoinStatus) As Integer
    Declare Auto Function NetApiBufferFree Lib "Netapi32.dll" (ByVal Buffer As IntPtr) As Integer
    Public Enum NetJoinStatus
        NetSetupUnknownStatus = 0
        NetSetupUnjoined
        NetSetupWorkgroupName
        NetSetupDomainName
    End Enum
End Class
```

As Well as Stephan's code here:

```
Dim cs As System.Management.ManagementObject
    Try
        cs = New System.Management.ManagementObject("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" + System.Environment.MachineName + "'")
        cs.Get()
        dim myDomain as string = = cs("domain").ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

I believe that only the second code will allow you to know what domain the machine joined, even if the current user IS NOT a domain member.

Answer (score 4):

The Environment variables could work for you.

```
Environment.UserDomainName
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx) for some more details.

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN")
```

I'm not sure this environment variable exists without being in a domain.

Correct me if I'm wrong Windows Admin geeks -- I believe a computer can be in several domains so it may be more important to know what domain, if any, you are in instead of it being in *any* domain.

Comment: As far as I'm aware a computer can only be joined to *one* domain - but you may be able to login to a PC using credentials from more than one domain in that forest, or from multiple forests if there are trusts set up. It all gets a bit too complicated there though =)

Comment: Environment.UserDomainName returns the computer name if the machine is not joined to domain. I suppose I can compare that with Environment.MachineName to determine if its domain joined, but I'm not sure if that will be correct in all situations.

Comment: @DSO - I know I'm chiming in late here but just in case someone stumbles upon this thread I just wanted to mention that even on a domain-joined machine if the user account the process is running under is a local account or system account, you can't rely on UserDomainName != MachineName.

Comment: @DSO, it will be. Domains and machines share a namespace.

Comment: @JoshEinstein Why can't you rely on UserDomainName != MachineName in the case where computer is joined to domain but current user running as local account?

Comment: @blak3r - Because a process running as a local user on a domain-joined machine will return the machine name, not the domain name, the same as if it were not domain-joined. The suggestion was to use that as an indication of domain joined or not.

Comment: @JoshEinstein I just posted a new answer.  If i'm misunderstanding, please let me know.

Comment: Joe Clancy also posted that method which should work just fine (though I still think it's better to P/Invoke instead of referencing a giant assembly for one method call.)

Answer (score 4):

You can check the PartOfDomain property of Win32_ComputerSystem WMI class.
The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says :

> PartOfDomain
>
> Data type: boolean
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> If True, the computer is part of a domain. If the value is NULL, the computer is not in a domain or the status is unknown. If you
>   unjoin the computer from a domain, the value becomes false.

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether the local machine is a member of a domain.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A boolean value that indicated whether the local machine is a member of a domain.</returns>
/// <remarks>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx</remarks>
public bool IsDomainMember()
{
    ManagementObject ComputerSystem;
    using (ComputerSystem = new ManagementObject(String.Format("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='{0}'", Environment.MachineName)))
    {
        ComputerSystem.Get();
        object Result = ComputerSystem["PartOfDomain"];
        return (Result != null && (bool)Result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike some other answers here, this one does appear to provide a solution for determining if the computer is joined to an AD domain.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my methods with exception handling / comments which I developed based on several of the answers in this post.

1. Gets you the domain the computer is connected to.
2. Only returns the domain name if the user is actually logged in on a domain account.

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Returns the domain of the logged in user.  
   /// Therefore, if computer is joined to a domain but user is logged in on local account.  String.Empty will be returned.
   /// Relavant StackOverflow Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926227/how-to-detect-if-machine-is-joined-to-domain-in-c
   /// </summary>
   /// <seealso cref="GetComputerDomainName"/>
   /// <returns>Domain name if user is connected to a domain, String.Empty if not.</returns>
   static string GetUserDomainName()
   {
       string domain = String.Empty;
       try
       {
           domain = Environment.UserDomainName;
           string machineName = Environment.MachineName;

           if (machineName.Equals(domain,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           {
               domain = String.Empty;
           }
       }
       catch
       {
           // Handle exception if desired, otherwise returns null
       }
       return domain;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Returns the Domain which the computer is joined to.  Note: if user is logged in as local account the domain of computer is still returned!
   /// </summary>
   /// <seealso cref="GetUserDomainName"/>
   /// <returns>A string with the domain name if it's joined.  String.Empty if it isn't.</returns>
   static string GetComputerDomainName()
   {
       string domain = String.Empty;
       try
       {
           domain = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetComputerDomain().Name;
       }
       catch
       {
           // Handle exception here if desired.
       }
       return domain;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try using the DomainRole WMI field. Values of 0 and 2 show standalone workstation and standalone server respectively.

We are using this for XIA Configuration our network audit software so I've cribbed the method here...

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether the local machine is a member of a domain.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A boolean value that indicated whether the local machine is a member of a domain.</returns>
/// <remarks>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx</remarks>
public bool IsDomainMember()
{
    ManagementObject ComputerSystem;
    using (ComputerSystem = new ManagementObject(String.Format("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='{0}'", Environment.MachineName)))
    {
        ComputerSystem.Get();
        UInt16 DomainRole = (UInt16)ComputerSystem["DomainRole"];
        return (DomainRole != 0 & DomainRole != 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution above returns false on a domain machine if a local user is logged in.

The most reliable method i have found is via WMI:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx (see domainrole)

Answer (score 1):

`Domain.GetComputerDomain()` can be extremely slow. In some environments it can take more than 30 seconds.

If performance matters, use [GetComputerNameEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
    bool IsComputerInDomain()
    {
        uint domainNameCapacity = 512;
        var domainName = new StringBuilder((int)domainNameCapacity);
        GetComputerNameEx(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT.ComputerNameDnsDomain, domainName, ref domainNameCapacity);
        return domainName.Length > 0;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool GetComputerNameEx(
        COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT NameType,
        StringBuilder lpBuffer,
        ref uint lpnSize);

    enum COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT
    {
        ComputerNameNetBIOS,
        ComputerNameDnsHostname,
        ComputerNameDnsDomain,
        ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified,
        ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS,
        ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname,
        ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain,
        ComputerNamePhysicalDnsFullyQualified
    }
```

It returns the same value as `systeminfo` shell command.

Answer (score 1):

You can check using **WMI**:

```
private bool PartOfDomain()
{
    ManagementObject manObject = new ManagementObject(string.Format("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='{0}'", Environment.MachineName));
    return (bool)manObject["PartOfDomain"];
}
```