# Finding out whether current machine is domain joined - looking for an efficient approach

Tags: c#

I'm trying to detect whether the current machine that executes a C# program is domain joined or not. So far I'm using

```
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetComputerDomain().ToString();
```

to read out the domain. If the computer is not domain joined it throws an error. This works. Unfortunately it makes the machine trying to connect to its PDC. If the machine has never been in a domain, it instantly returns the error. However, if the machine is a member of a domain but the PDC is not online, the function only returns after a timeout of almost a minute.

Is anybody aware of a more efficient approach to figure out whether a computer is domain joined? I'd prefer a pure local approach.

Comment: Take a look at [How to detect if machine is joined to domain (in C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926227/how-to-detect-if-machine-is-joined-to-domain-in-c?rq=1). Plenty of good answers to that question.

Comment: Great Link! Thanks! The last solution mentioned there worked perfectly!