# How to verify user logged in to domain or locally

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory

When my software is run my software most be get type of login of the windows user. Login by domain or local. I need to get type of login of the user in windows.

I think these APIs can help me:

```
GetComputerNameEx( ComputerNameDnsDomain, domainNameBuf, &bufSize );
```

or

```
GetUserName(sBuffer.GetBuffer(dwUsernameSize), &dwUsernameSize);
```

or

```
LookupAccountName(NULL, 
                  sUsername,
                  (PSID)pSid,
                  &dwSidSize,
                  sBuffer.GetBuffer(dwDomainNameSize), 
                  &dwDomainNameSize,
                  (PSID_NAME_USE)&sidType);
```

or

```
nStatus = NetWkstaUserGetInfo(NULL,dwLevel,(LPBYTE *)&pBuf);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if machine is joined to domain (in C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926227/how-to-detect-if-machine-is-joined-to-domain-in-c)

Comment: @AlexK: that's not a duplicate; this OP is asking whether the current user is logged into a domain account or a local one, not whether the computer is joined to a domain.  (You can still log in with a local account even when the machine is in a domain.)

Answer (score 6):

Use [`LsaQueryInformationPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `PolicyDnsDomainInformation` to retrieve the SID for the computer's primary domain.  If the `Sid` member is `NULL`, the computer is not joined to a domain and you can assume the user is logged into a local account.

Otherwise, use [`GetTokenInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `TokenUser` to retrieve the SID for the current user, then use [`GetWindowsAccountDomainSid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to extract the domain part of the user's SID.

Compare the primary domain's SID to the user's domain SID using [`EqualSid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If the SIDs are equal, the user is logged into a domain account; otherwise, the user is logged into a local account.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I know the computer joined to the my domain. please let me know how to detect the "user" was logged as "domain" state or logged as "this computer" state? thanks

Comment: @hessamini: I already did; finding out whether the computer is actually in a domain or not is just a side-effect.  Please read my answer more carefully.

Comment: this can be useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379554(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a simple way, why don't you just use [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retreive `USERDOMAIN` and then compare with `COMPUTERNAME`. If they are identical then the user is logged localy, in the other way the user is logged using the domain.

you also got the command line `WHOAMI.EXE` that gives you the information and the one I use is retreiving the WMI object `win32_computersystem`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [GetUserNameEx(NameUserPrincipal, ...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the UPN for the logged-in user. That will fail when run under a local account.