# How can I get the forest in which the current machine is registered?

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-4.5, directoryservices

At first, I am able to get the forest in which the **current user** is registered by the following code:

```
var lCurrentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
```

At second, I am able to get the domain in which the **current machine** is registered:

```
var lCurrentDomain = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
```

How can I get the forest in which the **current machine** is registered?

Comment: `Forest.GetForest(new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain));`? I can't test as I'm not on a domain with AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NetGetJoinInformation` Win32 API will give you the machine's domain. From there you can plug it in to something like this:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
//...
var forest = Domain.GetDomain(new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, <NetGetJoinInformationResult>)).Forest;
```

Comment: I can use my `IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;` and pass it in your suggested `Domain.GetDomain(...).Forest`. That works for me.

Comment: So that will work in most cases, but there is no guarantee that the machine's domain suffix matches the AD domain it is joined to.

Comment: Thank you for your evidence. Can you please tell my why there is no garantee? Do have a reference for your assertion?

Comment: It's called a Disjoint Namespace - here's a discussion of that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731125(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thank you. In Addition, I found a atricle on stackoverflow about that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926227/how-to-detect-if-machine-is-joined-to-domain-in-c. What do you think about using `Domain.GetComputerDomain().Name` instead `<NetGetJoinInformationResult>`? It seems to be easier to use.

Comment: Didn't know that API existed - that should do the job.