# Validating an user on the domain

Tags: c#, validation, dns

I need to validate an username against the domain and that works fine with this code. The challenge that I am facing is that when the system is not a part of the domain yet (in a workgroup) the user is not found. (but the system is connected to the domain because I am pinging it, just not a part of it yet)

Can anybody help me a bit on this? I want to validate the user on the domain when the system is still in the workgroup.

```
Ping domainserver = new Ping();
PingReply reply = domainserver.Send("ipadress domain server");

if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{

    using (var domianContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain"))
    using (var foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domianContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "username"))
        if (foundUser == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username is not found on the domain");
        }

        else
        {
         MessageBox.Show("Username is found on the domain");
        }
 }
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("It seems there is no network connection, please connect to the network first.");
}
```

Comment: Have checked this [How to detect if machine is joined to domain (in C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926227/how-to-detect-if-machine-is-joined-to-domain-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to work with the exceptions thrown from the Principal classes than doing it with ifs.

For example the, `new PrincipalContext` will fail if you are not a part of a domain.

```
try
{
    pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
}
catch (PrincipalServerDownException ex)
{
    //Domain is not accesible.
}
```

Depending on what actual you are trying to achieve you can also check the content of `Environment.UserDomainName` variable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I found the solution. When you run the script on the domain you do that with domain credentials, that's why it worked. When you are still on the workgroup (in my case) the account that was used did not have enough rights to see if the username exist on the domain. That is why it did not work.